# ECS Fargate Service - who needs to access KMS for Secrets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-fargate, amazon-kms

I;m trying to setup ECS Service that will run single task with MySQL and Webserver. I'd like to inject some runtime parameters as environmental variables from `SSM Parameter Store`. Some of them will be plain text but some will be encrypted with `KMS`. So suppose I have following task definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::657433956652:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/wordpress-test",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "name": "wordpress"
    },
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/wordpress-test",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "secrets": [
        {
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:657433956652:parameter/project/dev/db.connection.default.password",
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        }
      ],
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "name": "mysql"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::657433956652:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:657433956652:task-definition/wordpress-test:1",
  "family": "wordpress-test",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "512",
}
```

The question is: which role should receive access to read `SSM Parameter Store` and key used for encrypting `SecureString`s parameters? Should it be Service, Cluster or maybe even Pipeline that actually creates the service dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ecsTaskExecutionRole` should have permission to access SSM Parameter.

Create an inline policy and attach that policy to the `arn:aws:iam::657433956652:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole`

From documentation sample,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:<region>:<aws_account_id>:parameter/parameter_name",
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<aws_account_id>:secret:secret_name",
        "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<aws_account_id>:key/key_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html#secrets-iam